# How to split the text properly in python for glove?

Tags: python, split, nlp, stanford-nlp

In glove, punctuation like '.' is counted as a word. but in the case of u.s. and u.k. .it cannot be separated.

For example, there is a sentence.

he's going to u.s..

What glove want is ['he', ''s', 'going', 'to', 'u.s.', '.']
Are there any good ways to split that?

Comment: you can iterate over each value in the array and check the presence of `.`. if its there, remove it according to your need, as in convert `u.s` to `us` where as remove the `.` from array itself, if thats what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split the input the same way the input used in training was split. If you are using pre-trained vectors and don't know how they were generated, you can train your own vectors or ask the creator how they tokenized their input.

Also, as a note, sentences don't end with a double period even if the last word is an abbreviation.

```
wrong: He's going to the U.S..
right: He's going to the U.S.
```

You can read a more detailed explanation of that [here](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/ending-sentence-abbreviation).

Also note that in modern English it's very common to not use periods in abbreviations - as an example, [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/international) has sections for "US News" and  "UK News", without periods. As a practical matter, I think you don't need to worry about this particular issue unless it comes up a lot in your specific dataset.